# Passing data from Activity A to Service B to Activity C

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I want to pass data from Activity A to Service B which is `userName` and `phoneNumber`.
In Service B only `phoneNumber` (here phone number is important) is used and a `randomNumber` is generated. The data passed from Service B to Activity C is `userName`, `phoneNumber` and `randomNumber`.

I am trying to use this code given below but it does not work.

In activity A:

```
Intent goToServiceB = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ServiceB.class);
goToServiceB.putExtra("passedPhoneNumberAtoS", phoneNumberStr);
goToServiceB.putExtra("passedUserNameAtoS", userNameStr);
startService(goToServiceB);
```

In Service B:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("passedPhoneNumberAtoS");
    String userName = intent.getStringExtra("passedUserNameAtoS");
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

In Service B itself there is another intent:

```
Intent goToActivityC = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityC.class);
goToActivityC.putExtra("passedPhoneNumberStoA", phoneNumberStr);
goToActivityC.putExtra("passedUserNameStoA", userNameStr);
goToActivityC.putExtra("passedRandomNumberStoA", RandomNumberStr);
startactivity(goToActivityC);
```

In Activity C:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra("passedPhoneNumberStoA");
String userName = intent.getStringExtra("passedUserNameStoA");
String RandomNumber=intent.getStringExtra("passedRandomNumberStoA");
```

My logcat:

```
08-03 14:19:42.882: E/Trace(1923): error opening trace file: No such file or directory        (2)
08-03 14:19:44.983: D/gralloc_goldfish(1923): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-03 14:19:45.153: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1923): showStatusIcon on inactive   InputConnection
08-03 14:19:47.792: D/dalvikvm(1923): GC_CONCURRENT freed 84K, 7% free 2765K/2972K, paused 79ms+46ms, total 236ms
08-03 14:20:03.792: D/dalvikvm(1923): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 54K, 6% free 2931K/3104K, paused 36ms, total 57ms
08-03 14:20:03.812: I/dalvikvm-heap(1923): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.050MB for 1127536-byte allocation
08-03 14:20:03.964: D/dalvikvm(1923): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 50K, 6% free 3982K/4208K, paused 152ms, total 152ms
08-03 14:20:04.113: D/dalvikvm(1923): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 6% free 3987K/4208K, paused 4ms+97ms, total 154ms 
08-03 14:20:04.202: D/AndroidRuntime(1923): Shutting down VM
08-03 14:20:04.202: W/dalvikvm(1923): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930) 
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     ... 11 more
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923): Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:571)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:246)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at com.beproject.groupmessenger.UserRegistration.showAlert(UserRegistration.java:91)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     at com.beproject.groupmessenger.UserRegistration.submit(UserRegistration.java:97)
08-03 14:20:04.232: E/AndroidRuntime(1923):     ... 14 more
```

Can some one please give a simple solution to the above problem? I have searched a lot but am unable to get an understandable solution.

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Where does the data get lost?

Comment: My AVD shows a forced closed error after the 1st activity it self

Comment: What does your logcat say?

Comment: 1>java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method submit(View) in the activity class com.beproject.groupmessenger.UserRegistration for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'register'

2>error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Comment: This error indicates that the problem is completely unrelated to your data passing code. It sounds like you have a Button defined in XML with `onclick="submit"`, but the associated Activity lacks a `submit(View)` method.

Comment: Please update the question with your full logcat log. The logact is not very comment-friendly, especially when you need to break it up across three comments.

Answer (score 0):

In Service B you get the extras and store them in **local** String variables. These variables dissapear after you returned from `onStartCommand()` in that Service. So, whatever you pass to Activity C is not what you got from the Intent passed to `ServiceB.onStartCommand()`

You should have two String variables private to the Service Class and extract the extras to them.

EDIT: now with the logcat the error gets clearer. You define in your layout a button with id 'register'.  For this button you define with `android:onClick` to call a method `submit()`  in the Activity `UserRegistration`. This method does not exist.

You must implement this method as `public void submit(View view);` in UserRegistration to get it called. Android cannot detect this missing method (or.misspelled or ...) as it uses Reflection of Java at runtime.

Comment: Same error even after declaring the variables as private to Service Class

Comment: I see the logcat and the first error. Change sour code as suggested an check the logcat again. If this error is gone, you cm check for the next one.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method submit(View) in the activity class com.beproject.groupmessenger.UserRegistration for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'register'

The error from your logcat indicate that the problem is unrelated to your data passing code.

This error indicates that you have a Button with `android:id="@+id\register"` defined in the XML for your `UserRegistration` activity that also has a click handler set as `android:onclick="submit"`. However, Android could not find a `submit(View)` method in the `UserRegistration` Activity, and thus crashes with this error.

Make sure the `UserRegistration` Activity has a public `submit(View)` method, and the application should no longer crash.